# QLPreviewController is not working for Microsoft Intune SDK integrated application

Tags: ios, swift, intune

I have integrated Microsoft Intune SDK in my iOS application. In application want to show file preview in QLPreviewController.
It is not showing the preview in QLPreviewController. Same file can be preview in WKWebview, but don't want to use WKWebview in application. Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment on Microsoft git https://github.com/msintuneappsdk/ms-intune-app-sdk-ios/issues/242, issue is resolved for me. Coping same answer here

I have find out the root cause of this behavior.
It is due to how application shows QLPreviewController on parent/top view controller
let say "topController" is top most view controller for application and "qlPreviewController" is of QLPreviewController's object
To show QLPreviewController we have 2 use case

1. if topController is on navigation controller then

   topController.navigationController.pushViewController(qlPreviewController, animated: true)
2. or app can use "show"

   topController.show(qlPreviewController, sender: nil)

above 2 approach work for me as topController is on navigationController

Old issue in application was, it uses "present" method to launch "qlPreviewController".

```
topController.present(qlPreviewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

But "present" is working fine if application doesn't have Intune user enrol. And "present" fail in application when user enrolled with Intune policy in application